# Android - Alarm manager send notification immediately after app installed

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager

I have an Alarm Manager which sends notification for every 24 hours. If i install app to phone before alarm time everything is okay. However if i install app to phone after alarm time during day, it sends notification immediately. 
For example:
Alarm Time: 12.15
I installed app at time: 12.10 there is not any problem

Alarm time: 12.15
I installed app at time: 12.20 it send notification immediately however i want to send notification next day at 12.15:

I solved problem by getting the current time of system and comparing it with the alarm time. Is there another method of alarm manager class for this problem ?

here is my setting alarm code:

```
private void setAlarmTime()
{
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //bir gun
    int interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

    Log.v("alarm set", "alarm ayarlandi");
    userScreenPreference();
}
```

Comment: If `calendar` is before the current time, `add()` one day to it.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much